# Including one method multiple times in a test in testng.xml to execute steps multiple times

Tags: webdriver, testng

I want to execute a set of test methods multiple times as part of a test. 
I'm using TestNG to specify my tests. The test I have specified in the testng.xml file is this:

```
<test>
        <classes>
            <class name="AddAppointment">
                <methods>
                    <include name="testLogin" />
                    <include name="addAppointment" />
                    <include name="checkApptForCurrentLocation" />
                    <include name="changeLocation" />
                    <include name="addAppointment" />
                    <include name="checkApptForCurrentLocation" />
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
```

After executing this test, I saw that the repeated methods did not get executed. It executed the test only till 'changeLocation'.Could anyone suggest any other solution or reason why this is not working? 
 Please note that I don't want to execute the methods multiple times with different set of data. So using dataproviders as suggested in a few posts I found online will not help me. Because I'm following a strict order
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the point of running the same test method several times with the same data?

Comment: Also, the names of your test methods seem to imply that they are not real test methods but more used to change parameters ("changeLocation", "addAppointment"), it definitely looks like data providers are what you want.

Comment: executing changeLocation will take me to another view on the same page, where I want to execute addAppointment and checkApptForCurrentLocation again.

Comment: @CedricBeust: Can you please suggest an alternative? Couldn't this be included as a feature in TestNG? I don't think it's necessary that steps/method be executed multiple times only when you have multiple data.

Answer (score 1):

TestNG isn't a programming language and treating it as such will just lead to heartbreak. `addAppointment` and `changeLocation` are verbs in a programming language, not tests.

It looks like you have 3 tests: test for login, a test for a certain data combination in one (the default or starting) location, and a test for a certain data combination in another location. You glue these tests together using dependencies rather than sequencing using the methods/include construction.

In particular, I suggest that you set `testLogin` to be in a group with a name such as `startup`, and the first substantial test has a group-dependency on `startup`. The second substantial test has a method-dependency on the first substantial test.

Comment: Your answer is not related in anyway, to my problem. What has groups got to do with executing a method in a class multiple times inside a <test> ??